# Advantage of SanDisk iNAND?

Tags: memory, flash, sd, microsd, storage

I'm looking for a low-power [microSD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Physical_size) for a datalogger, when I came across [SanDisk's iNAND](http://www.sandisk.com/products/embedded/inand/) technology. What are some real-world advantages of those vs. microSD cards, except for their smaller physical dimensions?

Because many of the features they list seem like marketing-tricks, because normal SD cards have wear-leveling and error-correction too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iNAND products offer essentially the same functionality as microSDHC, but in a different package.

iNAND is not socketed; it is a BGA meant to be soldered directly to a PCB. Also, the electrical interface is different.

Comment: But except for their psycical appeareance, they don't use less power (or are more reliable) than microSDHC cards?